# BXslider doesn't load up correctly on Google Chrome for he first time, and then loads correctly later if refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I'm using multiple BXsliders on this website, and they're working well apart from [this one](http://incyberia.com/rsa4/Architecture1test.html)
If this doesn't happen on the browser you're using, [this is how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzGdr.jpg) the slider ends up being until the page is refreshed again
Help please! This page is the only place where this occurs. (I'm using a bxslider at the Architecture link too, without troubles)
Here's the slider script:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        pager: false
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the slider is instantiating before images are loaded in the slide and therefore the slide dimensions are not accurately detected.

Using something like images loaded (http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) should help you.

Wrap your code with the imagesloaded function like this:

```
$('.bxslider').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // images have loaded
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    pager: false
    });
});
```

I would also hide the images with css opacity until the slider is instantiated, then fade them.

Comment: Nope that doesn't help :/ Same thing's still happening. On the first loading of the page the slider is narrow like in the image, and once the whole page is loaded, refreshing it works every time

Comment: Can you post browser/os?

Comment: Windows 7/Google Chrome, as i said this issue is nonexistent on any other browser like Firefox or IE. Issue occurs on the android version of chrome too :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have solved the problem. The same occured to me. 
My problem is that I used 3.x jQuery. Swithed to 1.x and everything worked magically. Exact cause unknown though.

1.x for you:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js